# $\int _{S}\sin(y)dx+x\cos(y)dy$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

where $S=\left \{ (t,\sin(t^{2}))\mid t\in \left [ 0,\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \right ] \right \}$

Could you please give me some hints?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: note that $d\left( x\sin { \left( y \right)  }  \right) =\sin  (y)dx+x\cos  (y)dy$

Comment: @haqnatural thank you!